# Is Python logging thread safe still from within a docker container?

Tags: python, docker, logging, thread-safety

I'm trying to contenerise a Python application that relies on [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html). This library is declared to be thread safe. I'm just not sure "how safe" it is.

My idea es to run the docker container as `docker run --rm -it my_container`. This will create a log file within the container, that will be mapped to the filesystem in the host using `volume` (not explicitly shown in the command above because I still didn't sort out how to do that). Now, in practice, there will be several of such containers running in parallel in the host, all sharing the same log file (once I figure out how to do that).

Is this still thread safe? To what level is the safety implemented? We are not talking about "system threads", but different processes in different containers. They only share the file. Is this enough to ensure safeness in adding new lines from various processes without messing the file?

Comment: AFAIK no file locking is done under the hood, meaning logging is not cross-process safe. You could try setting up a logging service so that each of your process will connect to and log to it (which will then serialize those logs into the file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running multiple Docker containers, then you are running multiple processes. Thread safety relates to contention between multiple threads in a single process, so thread safety is irrelevant in this situation. Refer to [the official documentation relating to logging from multiple processes](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes).